# A simple AngularJS application for counting the number of gallons of paint

Tags: javascript, beginner, css, angular.js, dom

I created a simple Angular JS application for calculation gallons of paint needed to paint the ceiling of a room.

I assume one gallon covers 350 square feet and use it as a constant.
Also, I round up a counting of the gallons to the next whole number.
Now my code seems to me too simple).

I will be grateful for advice as it is possible to complicate this task with the use of AngularJS or next version of Angular.

```js
angular.module('my-App', [])
 .controller('paintCalculatorController', function($scope){
  $scope.length = 0;
  $scope.width = 0;
  const squareFeetForOneGallon = 350;
  $scope.square = function(){
   return $scope.length * $scope.width;
  }
  $scope.countGallon = function(){
   return Math.ceil($scope.length * $scope.width / squareFeetForOneGallon);
  }
 });
```

```css
form{
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="container text-center mx-auto mt-4 p-4"  style="width: 500px" ng-app="my-App" ng-controller="paintCalculatorController">
 <h3>Room ceiling area</h3>
  <form class="inline-form mt-3 py-3">
  <label>Length: </label>
  <input style="width:90px" type="number" ng-model="length" value="" name="" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
  <span> feet</span>
  <span class="ml-2 mr-2 font-weight-bold"> X </span>
  <label>Width : </label>
  <input style="width:90px" type="number" ng-model="width" value="" name="" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
  <span> feet</span>
    </form>
 <h4 class="mt-3">You will need to purchase {{countGallon()}} gallons of
 paint to cover {{square()}} square feet.</h4>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Simple code is good code. I'm not an angular guy, but I really don't see anything to complain about here besides maybe using `$scope.square` in `$scope.countGallon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Feedback

The code looks pretty good, and thus I only found a few things that I could change (listed below). I like how the bootstrap `text-center` class can be applied once to affect all sub-elements.

## Suggestions

### CSS

Move the in-line styles to the stylesheet to reduce redundancy - e.g. the number inputs have a specific width, which can be put into a CSS rule-set, like this example:

```
input[type="number"] {
  width: 90px;
}
```

Or apply a class name to those elements and utilize that class name in the selector. Also, the width of the container (i.e. `500px`) can be moved into a rule-set.

### JavaScript

#### Declaring the Constant

The idiomatic way of declaring a constant in AngularJS is to use [`.constant()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant) and use [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) to inject that constant in the controller.

```
.constant('SQUARE_FEET_FOR_ONE_GALLON', 350)
```

Then that value will be available for injection in the controller (this example uses the [implicit format](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation):

```
.controller('paintCalculatorController', function($scope, SQUARE_FEET_FOR_ONE_GALLON){
```

If nobody else is planning to work on this small amount of code with you, then using a plain JavaScript constant should be fine.

### Slight redundancy

Gerrit0 is correct in the comment: ["*maybe using $scope.square in $scope.countGallon*"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189342/a-simple-angularjs-application-for-counting-the-number-of-gallons-of-paint#comment362326_189342)

The function `countGallon()` can be updated to updated to utilize the `count()` function. The formula for the square footage likely won't change anytime soon, but if it did, then that could be updated in a single place instead of both places. This complies with the ***D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself* principle.

```
return Math.ceil($scope.count() / squareFeetForOneGallon);
```